# How to show all content types in dropdown list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, content-type

- I have full control of my SharePoint 2016 Online collection site.
- I have an Employee list with content types enabled.
- Each one of my 10 content types has its own set of columns.
- I have a default content type for a new form, while the others are not allowed on a new form.
- The default display, new and edit forms haven't been tampered with.

I used SharePoint Designer to create workflows that send emails to x department to take care of x new employee's needs.

Problem 1 (directing the user to any content type regardless of my "Set this field: Content-Type ID To this value: TheRightContentType") was taken care with a URL containing the id of the right content type. Not the best solution, but...

Problem 2 (Only showing 2 content types in my dropdown list on my Edit form). Well, I'm still stuck there.

I need to direct the user to the right content type (done), but **still give the choice to choose any of the 10 content types**.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.